# Changing settings in a dll file from other app

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2012, settings

I have an app.exe. I would like this app.exe to "grab" a needsettingschanged.dll file ( created with C# VS2012 ) on a specific drive and change it´s settings.
I am referring to the settings from my project > properties > settings in VS2012 ( C# ).
Is this completely nonsense or possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to modify the Needsettingschanged.dll.config manually via XML methods as you wont be able to access the settings via Needsettingschanged.Properties.Settings.Default.SettingName from another exe.

Comment: Thanks. Thing is there is no Needsettingschanged.dll.config, unless you are referring to some embedded resource I´m not aware of. All I got is the bare dll file, so as I read this I need to load the dll and expose an interface for writing to the Needsettingschanged.Propeties.Settings.Default.SettingName..